# Get instance by instance-id

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto

I need to get the instance by instance-id, is it possible to do it without requesting a list of all instances?

I've tried:

```
ec2_conn = boto.connect_ec2(aws_access_key_id=key, aws_secret_access_key=access)
c2.get_all_instances([instanceId])
```

It works, but is there some other way to get the instance?

The reason I'm asking is I received `UnauthorizedOperation` for `get_all_instances` request, so I would prefer to change the request, not the security settings.

Comment: when did u get UnauthorizedOperation ? I mean after which command execution

Comment: c2.get_all_instances([instanceId])

Answer (score 16):

Maybe `boto` has evolved since the time the OP asked the question, but this deserves the up to date answer to be added here:

```
reservations = ec2conn.get_all_instances(instance_ids=['i-12345678'])
instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
```

Comment: This gives you the reservation, not the instance.

Answer (score 8):

You can try with

```
reservations = ec2_conn.get_all_instances(filters={'instance-id' : 'i-xxxxxxxx'})
new_instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
```

it will definitely work.

Answer (score 3):

```
instances = get_only_instances(instance_ids=['i-12345678'])
```

Regarding the above answer using

```
get_all_instances()
```

, from the [BOTO API](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_instances) --

```
get_all_instances() is deprecated in favor of get_all_reservations(). 

A future major release will change get_all_instances() to return a list of 
boto.ec2.instance.Instance objects as its name suggests. 
To obtain that behavior today, use get_only_instances().
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Boto3 and just the instance-id, you want to use the describe instance call

```
import boto3
...

    response = client.describe_instances(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'string',
                'Values': [
                    'string',
                ]
            },
        ],
        InstanceIds=[
            'string',
        ],
        DryRun=True|False,
        MaxResults=123,
        NextToken='string'
    )
```

You can see more at the documentation https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances