# Python / Boto: How do I find out the details of the ec2 instance I just launched?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

Good day,

I am very new to Coding/Python so please give the answers like your speaking to a stupid person...I definitely won't be offended.

I am able to launch an ec2 instance successfully but I would like a way to see the details of the instance that I just launched. I would like to get back any kind of info such as the instance ID, IP address or anything like that. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

###Import the following arguments for the script
from sys import argv
script, base_ami, package = argv

print "Just launching a copy of", base_ami,"..."

import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1",
    aws_access_key_id='<key>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<secret>')

conn.run_instances('ami-df091bb6')
```

How do I find some info on the instance that I just launched?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of information ?

Comment: You've pasted working AWS credentials. These give anyone the ability to control your AWS resources. You need to deactivate these immediately - I just checked and they're working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to get the `reservation` object when you run your instance and from the reservation you can get the instance object. Once you get instance object you can query it but just calling its attributes.  The `conn.run_instances` method returns its current reservation so you can just do as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

###Import the following arguments for the script
from sys import argv
script, base_ami, package = argv

print "Just launching a copy of", base_ami,"..."

import boto.ec2
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1",
   aws_access_key_id='<key>',
   aws_secret_access_key='<secret>')

reservation = conn.run_instances('ami-df091bb6')

myinstance = reservation.instances[0]

# The get the instance id
myid = instance.id
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly for me. I now get back the instance ID successfully

Comment: What is the guarantee that this line will always return my instance on top of the list?

`reservation = conn.run_instances('ami-df091bb6')`

And, if there are thousands of instances in my account on that AMI, is it efficient?

Comment: @Baskar you can get multiple instances if you are starting several instances with the same AMI for example. If you want a specific set of instances you will have to find them based on their attributes. If you are launching a single instance, then your first instance will always be the one you want.. More info  on reservations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618825/what-is-the-purpose-of-reservations-in-amazon-ec2

Comment: The question is about getting the instance that you just launched.. If there are parallel such programs running, this one cant guarantee you ll be on top always.

This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096241/get-instance-by-instance-id

Comment: @Baskar nope. Right, you can try filtering like the question/answer you mentioned